# Game Maker 7 GML array length

Tags: arrays, game-maker-language, game-maker-legacy

I am working in Game Maker 7 using GML in order to create a Main Menu for my game. I have looked for a while now trying to find out what the code is to use the length of an array however I cannot find it. What I have so far is:

```
var move = 0;
move -= max(keyboard_check_pressed(vk_up),(keyboard_check_pressed(ord("W")),0);
move += max(keyboard_check_pressed(vk_down),(keyboard_check_pressed(ord("S")),0);

if (move != 0)
{
    mpos += move;
    if (mpos <0) mpos = array_length_1d(menu) - 1;
    if (mpos > array_length_1d(menu) - 1) mpos = 0;
}

var push;
push = max(keyboard_check_released(vl_enter),keyboard_check_released(vk_shift),keyboard_check_released(vk_space), 0);
if (push == 1) Scr_Menu();
```

This is meant to cycle through the array and make sure that the menu arrow doesn't go where a option is. The error I am receiving is:

> FATAL ERROR in action number 1 of  Step Event for object Obj_Menu:
>
> COMPILATION ERROR in code action Error in code at line 8:
> if (mpos <0) mpos = array_length_1d(menu) - 1;
>
> at position 26: Unknown function or script: array_length_1d

Comment: Seems the code is not the one you compiled. Because there is no "array_get_length_1d" in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should write `array_length_1d` instead of `array_get_length_1d`.
"get" is unnecessary.

Comment: The function array_length_1d does not seem to be in GameMaker 7 or 8.